# Cordova SQLite: database already open: data.db

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to implement a chat app in Ionic 2 and I use SQLite.

I am however, getting the following error when I execute a `executeSql` on the database.

> TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'executeSql'
>   of undefined"}

But when I open the databse each transaction, I don't get the above error, but get the following warning:

> database already open: data.db

I have been reading the [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) and [Cordova](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database) documentation, but cannot seem to understand what I am doing incorrect. If anyone can advise, I would appreciate it.

**chatsStorageService.ts**

```
public openDatabase(): Promise<Array<Message>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Message>> = new Promise<Array<Message>>(resolve => {
        console.log('openDatabase: ', this.database);
        if (this.database && this.database != null) {
            return Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                resolve(this.messages);
            });
        } else {
            this.database = new SQLite();
            this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then(() => {
                return Promise.all([this.refreshChats(this.database), this.refreshMessages(this.database)]).then(() => {
                    resolve(this.messages);
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
            });
        }
    });
    return promise;
}

public refreshChats(db: any): Promise<Array<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Array<Chat>> = new Promise<Array<Chat>>(resolve => {
        return db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM chats", [])
            .then((chatData) => {
                let promises: Array<any> = [];
                this.chats = [];
                if (chatData.rows.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < chatData.rows.length; i++) {
                        promises.push(this.populateChat(db, chatData.rows.item(i)));
                    }
                }
                return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    resolve(this.chats);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("ERROR REFRESHING CHATS: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                console.log(error);
            });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Should I open and close the database for each transaction? Or just leave it open?